# How to change the collation of user-defined table types

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have a scenario in which a user-defined table type has been used as a parameter in multiple stored procedures. This user defined table type has a column with char data type and older collation.

This collation is not suitable to our application and we want to change it to another collation.

What would be the best way to do this? Can we recreate the user defined table type with new collation? if yes, then how to deal with dependent stored procedures?

Comment: So, it will be like create a new UDTT with new collation and then change all the dependent SPs to use this new UDTT and then I can drop the older UDTT. And after dropping the older UDTT, I can rename the new UDTT with the name of older UDTT.

Comment: Can you pl give me steps to achieve it without changing the name of UDTT

Comment: ok got it, your first two comments...Thank you